# Customize ag-Grid header component for updating column cell data

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to implement ag-Grid in angular.

Here what is my requirement.

1. Each cell under the 'Name' (header) column needs to be updated to the value I entered in the 'Set default column data' (input field).

"The input field (set default column data) will popup when we press the header 'Name'"

[image]

- Need output like below screenshot

[image]

I didn't find any relatable document for it.
Any one have any reference please feel free to support.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your English is very difficult to understand. If English is not your first language, you can also use Google Translate. I'm still not quite sure what you want anyway.

For custom headers you have the documentation here:
[ag-grid header rendering](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#angular-header-component)

For custom header components use `headerComponentFramework` and if you want to send properties to the header you can use `headerComponentParams` (Explanation about [properties](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#complementing-params))

In the custom header component (headerComponentFramework) you can set your new value "Martin" and overwrite your table-data array with the new value.

Comment: 'In the custom header component (headerComponentFramework) you can set your new value "Martin" and overwrite your table-data array with the new value.'  if you don't mind will you please share an example code for how to  get the table-data array in header component or how to update the table-data array in  header component. actually i didn't get table-data array in params payload of header component,
thank you,